# Interpreting output from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been stuck a few hours on this little problem that I have and would be thankful if anyone could help.

My ultimate goal here is to get all the unique states and link each of those states with it's page which will show all communities that this state belongs_to.

I have tried fiddling around with 2 alternatives, alt.1 gives me an array which makes it easy fit into an .each loop but no id to find communities with. alt.2 gives me the id & state but the output is in a format that I don't recognize.

```
# model
class Community...
has_one :location

class Location...
belongs_to :community

# view
# alt.1
Location.pluck("DISTINCT state")

# alt.2
Location.select('distinct on(state) id, state')
=> [#<Location id: 2, state: "Oakland">, #<Location id:4, state: "South Carolina">]
```

Solution for both or alternative alternatives extra appreciated.

Comment: alt2 is an array where each element is an active record

Comment: i guess second one alt2 is perfect. you can traverse and fetch id and state from each one. but second one will give you only one id for state. not all.

Comment: Thanks, solved it! Didn't recognize the ActiveRecord elements because I have never seen it in it's "raw" form.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) As Athar said, the second is correct, and they are activerecord objects.  A more activerecord way to do this would be `Location.select('state').uniq.map(&:state)`, which will return an array of states.

2) Read the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html - I don't think `select` does what you think it does.

3) It may be useful for you in the future to have a states table, which you clearly would not need to populate with initial values from a migration, instead of just having it as a string column on location.  You could then enforce that a location references an existing state.